# Cannot validate email values in restapi using restassured

Tags: java, rest-assured, web-api-testing

can someone please assist, I'm using restassured to pull and display results from this server https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/9/comments, but cannot verify the emails of this user and display accurate data. Here is my code below:

```
public static void getPostComments() {
        System.out.println("===============Comments By User==================");


        given().when().get(url + "/posts/9/comments").then().log()
                .body();

        Response res = given().when().get(url + "/posts/9/comments");
        List<String> jsonRes = res.jsonPath().getList("email");

                if (jsonRes.equals("Lucio@gladys.tv")) {

        given().queryParam("id", "9")
                .get("http://localhost:3000/posts/9/comments/")
                .then()
                .assertThat()
                .body("email["+String.valueOf(0)+"]", Is.is("Lucio@gladys.tv"))
                .log()
                .body();

    }

 }
```

The results I get from the above code, just returns all the users without validating. I'm fairly new to restassured, but would appreciate any pointers to validate these emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do that.

Example 1:

```
given()
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/9/comments")
        .then()
        .assertThat()
        .body("email", hasItem("Lucio@gladys.tv"));
```

Example 2:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItem;

List<String> emails = given()
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/9/comments")
        .jsonPath()
        .get("email");

assertThat(emails, hasItem("Lucio@gladys.tv"));
```

Comment: Thanks mate, been looking for different options on this library, mind sharing the link to the documentation?

Comment: here you are https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#response-body and Hamcrest http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html